# Unable to find snapshot dependencies after gradle upgrade from 1.12 to 2.14

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies, repository, snapshot

After `gradle` upgrade from `1.12` to `2.14`, the snapshot versions of the dependencies in a maven repository are not identified. The repository is set up properly and the `maven-metadata.xml` and the dependencies exists, and it builds with the 1.xx versions of gradle. Could not find anything from the gradle release notes for 2.xxx either. Has anyone come across this situation?
Following is my build.gradle file.

```
// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
// Use 'maven central' for resolving your dependencies.
// You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
mavenCentral()
 maven {
    name = 'Public'
    credentials {
        username = 'abc'
        password = 'abc'
    }
    url 'http://mydomain/nexus/content/groups/public/'
}

}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test   code
dependencies {
// The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
compile( 

[group: 'com.test.comp', name: 'comp-app-interface', version: "3.0.9_SNAPSHOT"],
[group: 'com.test.comp', name: 'comp-app-common', version: "3.0.10_SNAPSHOT", classifier: 'lib'],
)
// Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
// TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
// testCompile dependency to testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
// 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
}
```

Following is the error message that I get when building with gradle 2.14:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

\* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':COMP-Testing-  Common:compileClasspath'.

\> Could not find com.test.comp:comp-app-common:3.0.10_SNAPSHOT.
 Searched in the following locations:
  file:/C:/Users/myname/.m2/repository/com/test/comp/comp-app-common/3.0.10_SNAPSHOT/comp-app-common-3.0.10_SNAPSHOT.pom
  file:/C:/Users/myname/.m2/repository/com/test/comp/comp-app-common/3.0.10_SNAPSHOT/comp-app-common-3.0.10_SNAPSHOT-lib.jar
  http://example.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/test/comp/comp-app-common/3.0.10_SNAPSHOT/comp-app-common-3.0.10_SNAPSHOT.pom
  http://example.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/test/comp/comp-app-common/3.0.10_SNAPSHOT/comp-app-common-3.0.10_SNAPSHOT-lib.jar
  Required by:
  com.test.comp:COMP-Testing-Common:3.0.10
```

> 

But when building with gradle 1.12, it downloads the proper snapshot.

Comment: Can you post your build file?

Comment: It seems right. However, what do you mean by 'it builds with the 1.xx versions of gradle'? And are you getting any errors when you build? If so, can you post the error messages as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found and fixed the issue.
Gradle does not identify that they were snapshots because of the format of the version number.
eg: when there is an underscore between the version number and 'snapshot', `3.0.9_SNAPSHOT` gradle simply looks for the dependency with that version. But if it has a dash instead of the underscore in between (i.e `3.0.9-SNAPSHOT`), gradle will read the `maven-metadata.xml` and finds the latest snapshot.
The underscore was working fine when using gradle 1.xxx versions.

Comment: OMG after DAYS of trying to figure out this Gradle quirk, this actually worked for me! The Gradle team should really put this in their documentation!

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the required dependency `com.test.comp:comp-app-common:3.0.10_SNAPSHOT` is not in any of the specified repositories. Please check first whether gradle is right or wrong about that (by looking into the given repositories).

To correct the error, check whether all relevant repositories are included. If the error still occurs, delete your local Maven repository and Gradle cache and try again.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have checked that the dependencies exist and the repositories added to the build file, and cleaned gradle cache and removed local maven repo and tried again as you suggested, still getting the same issue.